# Good style to avoid global variables in C++

Tags: c++, variables, design-patterns, global, local

In much different projects, I got sooner or later some errors/warnings/problems while using global variables. Is there style a good program design to use global variables right in my projects or to avoid it completely

I read much articles about this issue and all are telling the same: Replace global variables with local variables, context objects, different patterns (singleton) and such things, but there are no explicit examples and descriptions how to use it right.

Do you have some good hints or references about that theme?

Comment: The others are good, but "different patterns (singleton)" will not help at all: it's the same thing, but with other bad ideas on top. My personal favourite is the environment/reader monad but most mainstream languages are not cool enough for that.

Comment: Use a singleton as global object. Sometimes you will just make look a programm like hell without something global. YOu will always need to pass around every information needed. Most problems would come if you cannot make it thread safe and use threads.

Comment: @Offler No. No no no no no. That's just lazy. Do it right instead of using an ugly patch like a singleton.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Thats just philosophical right. Not using a singleton makes your program mostly sluggish, having methods just passing through hundreds of configurations (where most methods will never touch or have anything to do with the information) and so on. Nobody should even think about forwarding a configuration through dozends of methods. That will make much things more unreadable. Object orientated programming is not functional programming. So don't use the fallbacks of a functional program. Also using globals will sometimes improve permorfamnce significally over passing around thing.

Comment: @Offler There are so many things wrong in that comment I don't know where to start.

Comment: @Offler could you perhaps show us a code base where, because singletons are not used, you instead have methods "passing through hundreds of configurations they never touch"? Because it is not my expereince that this happens when you avoid singletons. Instead, you find out that "oh, I didn't actually *need* to pass so many dependencies around, I can just clean up my code instead". So again, can you show some *evidence* to back up your claim about what happens when you don't use singletons?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Have one of you ever seen a logging framework which does not act as singleton or as global object? What do you think does AOP or IOC do? you put away repetive things from code. If you look around through code passes you will never pass around the configuration for where to write a log file to. Why do you think that logger like log4net are used as singleton? It may not happen in very small projects that you need somethign like a global variable or singleton, but to never use it makes thigns a lot mor complicated.

Comment: @jalf see above. you wont ever pass around the configuration where to log something to. you will either have a local object or a singleton, log4net for example shows that behaviour well. Even AOP/IOC show a general behaviour: put repetive things in something which is not passed around in code. The decorators only hide that you are using a global log mechanism, a global exception handler, a global... and so on. Its just hidden that something like ninject glues together things you repet. do and the compiler will put things together for you.

Comment: @Offler correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure you talked about **hundreds** of configurations. Have you ever seen a logger which, if it wasn't a singleton, required you to pass **hundreds** of values around? (Apart from that, I would generally accept a logger being *global* (not a *singleton*, but I can accept it being global), but nothing else. For your "hundreds" of other values, you should definitely pass those around to where they are needed (because that way a reader of the code can *see* where they are needed, and that way you will ensure they aren't "needed" *everywhere*

Comment: @jalf no,  i'm talking about passing of configurations or objects through dozends of methods. For example: pass a logger configuration or object through every method in classes just to have it log something in the last method, but don't need it in between. Pass your (fixed during program flow) database information around instead of using a single, threadsafe database accessor. Other way around: throw an error and in every possible method use try{}catch{throw;} just to get it in the calling class. This sort of things only make code filled with unneccessary information

Comment: let me remind you of what you said: " Not using a singleton makes your program mostly sluggish, having methods just passing through hundreds of configurations (where most methods will never touch or have anything to do with the information)". Now, please provide some evidence to back up that absurd claim (both the "sluggish" part, and the "having to pass hundreds of objects around that most methods never touch")

Answer (score 2):

singletons are very similar to global variables in the problems they cause.  Try looking at the "Parametrisation From Above" pattern instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is a though task to get rid of global variables. Obviously there might be some strictly necessary, those will most likely be declared in your main or in header files. 
A good example of global variable is a "struct" for parsing options from a configuration file: you load it once at the beginning of the execution and then you can keep accessing it from everywhere else. Or, you could also do the same with an object with set/get methods to retrieve those same config options (but still, the object would be declared global).

Also do not underestimate the power of macros. Whatever you decide to do, never forget the basic principle: DRY, Don't Repeat Yoursef. Keep things simple and keep them stored one place only.

Comment: What if you want to inject some mock settings for automated testing purposes? Then you can't just have one global variable for it.

Comment: Then you could implement some command line options or just ad-hoc configuration file (supposing there is already a parsing functionality). They could both be related to the same class, eventually.